# Making text bold in an email in PL/SQL

Tags: html, sql, plsql

I am trying to format text in the variable var_sub_title bold before sending it in email bold.

```
  declare
  var_sub_title varchar2(60);
  var_txt varchar2(500);
  var_msg_sub varchar2(60);
  
  begin
  select sub_title, txt, subject into var_sub_title, var_txt, var_msg_sub from table where msg_id = :id;
     -- SEND EMAIL --
  HTMLDB_MAIL.SEND(
       P_to   => 'email@mail.com',
       p_from =>'email@email.net',
       p_body => var_sub_title||CHR(10)||CHR(13)||var_txt||CHR(10)||CHR(13);                
       p_subj => var_msg_sub); 
   htmldb_mail.push_queue;
  end;
```

how can i archiev this?

Comment: Since the body is in html, you can wrap your text with `b` tag: `<b>text</b>`

Comment: I tried adding the  <b>var_sub_title</b> in the body but the tags are being included in the email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [documentation](http://www.cis.famu.edu/support/10g/Oracle_Database_10g/doc/appdev.102/b14303/api.htm#CHDDHBGI) says, you need to pass your HTML-formatted text to parameter `p_body_html`, not `p_body`:

> Plain text and HTML e-mail content. Passing a value to `p_body`, but not `p_body_html` results in a plain text message. Passing a value to `p_body` and `p_body_html` yields a multi-part message that includes both plain text and HTML content.

So your code should be:

```
declare
  var_sub_title varchar2(60);
  var_txt varchar2(500);
  var_msg_sub varchar2(60);
  
  begin
  select sub_title, txt, subject into var_sub_title, var_txt, var_msg_sub from table where msg_id = :id;
     -- SEND EMAIL --
  HTMLDB_MAIL.SEND(
       P_to        => 'email@mail.com',
       p_from      => 'email@email.net',
       p_body_html => '<b>'|| var_sub_title || '</b>' || CHR(10) || CHR(13) || var_txt || CHR(10) || CHR(13);                
       p_subj      => var_msg_sub); 
   htmldb_mail.push_queue;
  end;
```

Also there are other restrictions on length and ability to process HTML emails by recipient's email client.

> When using HTMLDB_MAIL.SEND, remember the following:
>
> - No single line may exceed 1000 characters. The SMTP/MIME specification dictates that no single line shall exceed 1000 characters. To comply with this restriction, you must add a carriage return or line feed characters to break up your p_body or p_body_html parameters into chunks of 1000 characters or less. Failing to do so will result in erroneous e-mail messages, including partial messages or messages with extraneous exclamation points.
> - Plain text and HTML e-mail content. Passing a value to p_body, but not p_body_html results in a plain text message. Passing a value to p_body and p_body_html yields a multi-part message that includes both plain text and HTML content. The settings and capabilities of the recipient's email client determine what displays. Although most modern e-mail clients can read a HTML formatted email, remember that some users disable this functionality to address security issues.
> - Avoid images. When referencing images in p_body_html using the  tag, remember that the images must be accessible to the recipient's e-mail client in order for them to see the image